# Connect mongodb 4.0 with robomongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I am facing an issue with the mongodb **4.0**. I have setup mongodb on remote server and want to connect it with robo3t. But getting the below error.

[image]

And here is my **mongodb.conf** file

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
 #authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Mongodb version --> **4.0**
Os --> **ubuntu 16.04**

Update-->

[image]

Comment: How are you starting your MongoDB server (i.e. using a service definition or passing parameters manually)?  You can use `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` in the `mongo` shell to check that your options are being correctly parsed. Assuming there are no errors starting MongoDB with your example config, `mongod` should be listening to all network interfaces and any basic remote access issues are likely related to your O/S or hosting firewalls (i.e. AWS Security Groups). I'd strongly recommend enabling auth, access control, and TLS/SSL to secure your deployment before opening it up on a public network.

Comment: Please review the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for more information including links to tutorials. I also recommend testing your config with the matching 4.0 `mongo` shell before trying third party tools. Robo3T isn't actively updated and embeds a specific version of the `mongo` shell (the current 1.2 release is based on the `mongo` 3.4.3 shell). For best outcomes I would recommend using an actively updated tool that explicitly mentions support for your MongoDB server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the MongoDB service is running in the remote machine.

Next, check if the MongoDB port is open to the outside network or not.

The following will help you check if the 27017 is accessible from an outside machine.

```
nmap -Pn 13.56.140.11
```

If the port is not enabled, use the following command to expose the port.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it didn't work.

Comment: Are you able to connect using mongo shell? Also, can you post the error message you get when connect using robo mongo by clicking on `show error details`.

Comment: Yes I am able to connect using mongoshell. Even my code nodejs code is properly working over there. Only problem is I am not able to connect using robo31 or compass as well. Please check the updated question for the `error details`

Comment: Please refer this link question also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521387/3432487

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I have not opened 27017 port on my aws instance

Comment: It was nowhere mentioned that the MongoDB is hosted in an AWS EC2 instance, so was not able to give you the exact answer.

Comment: Apologies for that